# join group_price to product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, group-price, join-table

When I get the product collection with :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

I get the group_price key but it's empty.

```
 Array
 (
    [entity_id] => 1
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 2
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => 00000
    ......
    [group_price] => Array
        (
        )

    ......
)
```

And if I load the product I can get the group_price data with :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$group_price = $product->getData('group_price');
```

I tried different query with joinField() or joinTable() with table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' but without success.

How to join group_price data to the collection with a join query ?

I would like to avoid iterating the collection to load each product and get the group_price.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->addAttributeToSelect('group_price')`

Comment: I use ->addAttributeToSelect() with some attributes, eg 'color'. This add the value to the collection.. unfortunately not for 'group_price'